# Which are the V8 current values on node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8

When executing a node application, you can tweak a lot of v8 values.

Is it somehow possible to check from the source code being executed the value of those options?

My particular interest is on checking max_semi_space_size and max_old_space_size, in case the is a workaround to know those values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In node.js you can use the v8 module: https://nodejs.org/api/v8.html

You can also use this package. I think it suit you well:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/v8-flags

To list available flags: `node --v8-options`